# Tkinter Scroll Event Not Propagating to Canvas in Complex Layout

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, frame, mousewheel

I'm working on a Tkinter application where I have a `Canvas` widget alongside a vertical `Scrollbar`. Nested inside the canvas, I have multiple `Frame` widgets that represent clickable and scrollable content. Each frame contains clickable elements that also should not interfere with the canvas scrolling.

Despite binding the scroll event to the canvas and all child widgets, the scroll event does not trigger when hovering over the frames, although it works when hovering over the scrollbar itself. Here's a simplified structure of the layout:

```
root
└─ right_container (Frame)
   ├─ news_container (Frame)
   │  ├─ news_canvas (Canvas)
   │  └─ news_scrollbar (Scrollbar)
   └─ news_frame (Frame, inside Canvas)
      └─ multiple child widgets (Frames, Labels, etc.)
```

The expected behavior is for the canvas to scroll regardless of where the mouse pointer is positioned over the canvas or its child widgets. However, scrolling only works when the mouse is over the scrollbar or the empty space of the canvas, not over the child widgets of the `news_frame`.

I've attempted to bind the `<MouseWheel>` event to all child widgets, but the issue persists. Here's a snippet of the binding:

```py
for child in news_frame.winfo_children():
    child.bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)
```

And the `on_mousewheel` function looks like this:

```py
def on_mousewheel(event):
    news_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest what might be going wrong? Any insights or alternative approaches to ensure the scroll event propagates properly would be greatly appreciated.

See image.  This is a screen grab of the News Container. Inside is a news canvas, scrollbar, and news frames each of the articles make up a news frame with multiple widgets for the thumbnail, title, description, publication date, and source)  I want to be able to scroll anywhere over the news canvas so I can see all the search results.

[image]

Comment: This link might help    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter